# Sitecore security permissions and standard values

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore7

Here is a simplistic summary of my module in `Sitecore`:

> - Module Folder
>
>   - Venue Item (multiple)
>   - - Complete Bookings
>   - - - Booking Item (multiple)
>   - - Incomplete Bookings
>   - - - Booking Item (multiple)

There are many venue item and each have two folders underneath for `complete/incomplete` bookings which in turn have many booking items underneath them.

I'm setting up workflow roles and need to craft three roles:

> - Venue Editing
> - Venue Approving
> - Booking Managing

These are all easy to setup and secure the correct `create/write/delete` rights but my issue is that I have, per requirement, disabled inherent read access to the `Complete/Incomplete` folders as most Sitecore users should not have access to that information. I need to give one specific role read access to these folders and I'm not 100% on how to utilise (is possible) standard values to implement the persmissions.

I can't go into security editor and give each specific `complete/incomplete` folder read access as the venues will be `created/deleted` on an ongoing basis. Standard values doesn't seem to copy over its security settings to items instantiated from it. Am I correct in believing this?

Is my only option to set security settings via an event handler or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Look into using Template level security, that way it is not based on the content locaiton: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Security/Common%20Security%20Concepts/Security%20concepts/Templates%20and%20rights.aspx

Comment: Sounds like a case for using Branch Templates. Take a look at chapter 3 (section 3.6) of this document: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Data%20Definition%20Cookbook.aspx

Comment: I considered using branches but they're created via user input integrated with a payment gateway so preferred to keep it managed with a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jammykam for his helpful comment.

I was going in that direction at first but had forgotten that the permissions aren't retroactively applied to existing items so my test items indicated it wasn't working properly at first.

All sorted now.